# Could you use a DAC to scale and modify an input signal?

Tags: analog, signal-processing, dac

We are getting an input signal and need to modify it without changing the phase, would it be possible to do this by feeding it into a DAC through the reference voltage pin?

Comment: Might need a fair amount of buffering before and after the DAC, which *will* change the phase.

Comment: "a DAC" (what DAC), modify input signal (*how* and *how much*)...without changing the phase (*how much*). The device doesn't exist that you can send a signal through with 0.000* phase change, so can you give us some engineering (i.e. physically possible) criteria for what you're wanting us to help you accomplish? -- Until the necessary criteria are added, I'm voting to close as "too Broad," however the close vote can & will be retracted if you edit your question to give us the information we need to help you.

Comment: related: [Altering reference voltage of DAC](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/202320/altering-reference-voltage-of-dac)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For many D/As, yes that works.  Sometimes devices were designed deliberately for this type of operation and called *Multiplying DACs*.

Check the bandwidth and delay from reference to output carefully.  These might not be what you expect from looking at the number to analog value delay spec.

Although you say "modify" in your question, the only thing such a DAC can do with your signal is attenuate it, with some unavoidable delay and low pass filtering.